# Grails 3 Interceptors as a plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, interceptor, grails-controller, grails-3.0

I'm trying to convert a Grails 2 controller filter into a Grails 3 interceptor.  The interceptor is in a Grails plugin.  The Grails 3 upgrade is done, and when I copy and paste the code into an app (just to verify it works), then I see the output from the interceptor.

However, if I try to pull in that code through a plugin to the app, the interceptors do not run. I can verify that the plugin is being pulled; its interceptors are just not being invoked when I hit an action.

For example if the plugin is:

```
// If added to app directly, works fine. As plugin, not invoked.
class SimpleInterceptor {
    SimpleInterceptor() {
        matchAll()
    }

    boolean before() {
      println 'test' // Does not print if using plugin
    }
}
```

And the controller is a simple action:

```
def index() {
   render 'success'
}
```

Do I need to register it somehow in order for the interceptor to work on apps?  Am I missing a step?

Comment: I havent messed about, but noticed there was this  plugin that appears to have it working https://github.com/appcela/grails3-cors-interceptor. Hope it is of help

Comment: Oh interesting, thanks @vahid, I'll check it out.  I had seen https://github.com/agorapulse/grails-newrelic also, but I could not for the life of me figure out what he was doing that I was not, and why it wasn't working (and unfortunately couldn't check it against my test project since it requires NewRelic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@vahid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/755637/vahid) for pointing out a repo that was doing something similar.  Turns out the issue I had was when I upgraded my plugin's `*Plugin.groovy` file, I didn't extend `grails.plugins.Plugin`.  Be sure to do that, or the plugin may not get picked up by apps.